# Is true that $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $s-k>n/p$?.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

In Functional Analysis by J. Cerda, the theorem 7.28 says:

theorem 7.8. If $s-k>n/2$ then $H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (functions $k$ times differentiable)
with $H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n):=\left\{u\in L^2: \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}(u))\in L^2\right\}$

Let 
$H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n):=\left\{u\in L^p: \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}(u)\in L^p\right\}$ Sobolev space.

I know that if $s>n/p$ then $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ [Taylor,Partial Differential equations  III, prop. 6.3, p.26]

Is there a similar result in the context of $L^p$? e.g.

If $s-k>n/p$, the Sobolev space $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: this question is a copy of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592102/is-true-that-hs-p-mathbbrn-subset-ck-mathbbrn-when-s-kn-p. You should edit *that* question and wait for it to be reopened. In particular you should add details of what you have tried eg have you tried repeatedly applying the result you already know